# How do I get out of Geirmund's Hall alive?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was exploring Skyrim, so I was walking around, and I happened to come here by falling through a hole in the ground. I'm just level 3, so is there any way to get out of here alive? Or do I have to restart the game?

Comment: Oh okay.. sorry, I just started using this website so I don't know how to use it yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can always lower the [difficulty settings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/35941/4797) (and revert it back later) when you're having a hard time on a particular area or quest.

Also, see the UESP wiki article about [Geirmund's Hall](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Geirmund%27s_Hall) for a walkthrough and tips on how to navigate and get out of that area.